# How to set the default options on an existing plugin in a WP MU new user install

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

When a new user signs up in WP MU install I would like to set the default options for a plugin that I have installed in the super admin account. I've read through so many posts but have not found out how to do this.

Comment: This is a plugin specific functionality.  You should go to the plugin support site to see if you can do that.  It is not trivial for most users to do what you are asking.  You would either need to modify your theme or write a new plugin.

Comment: OK. I posted a question in the plugin forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the api.php page before the `class JSON_API` line add the following code:

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'wpse_set_defaults' );

function wpse_set_defaults( $blog_id ) {
    global $json_api;

    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

    // set the default controllers here
    $required_controllers = explode(",", "categories,posts,user,attachments");

    $id = 'json_api_controllers';

    $available_controllers = $json_api->get_controllers();
    $active_controllers = explode(',', get_option($id, 'core'));
    $action = "activate";

    foreach ($required_controllers as $controller) {
        if (in_array($controller, $available_controllers)) {
            if ($action == 'activate' && !in_array($controller, $active_controllers)) {
                $active_controllers[] = $controller;
            } else if ($action == 'deactivate') {
                $index = array_search($controller, $active_controllers);
                if ($index !== false) {
                    unset($active_controllers[$index]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $value = implode(',', $active_controllers);

    // get option and set it
    $option_exists = (get_option($id, null) !== null);

    if ($option_exists) {
        update_option($id, $value);
    } else {
        add_option($id, $value);
    }

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

You can set other options here as well.